# _pygit2.GitError: user rejected certificate when Salt is trying to connect

Tags: salt-stack

First time using Salt, and first post - so apologies for the newbie question.

I’m trying to integrate SaltStack with GitLab to use as a fileserver backend following this document: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html

When defining the gitfs fileserver in Salt, I am getting these errors on the Salt master log:

```
2021-06-29 16:10:27,559 [salt.utils.gitfs :1893][ERROR   ][1011] Error occurred fetching gitfs remote 'https://git.xxx.local/root/ssc.git': user rejected certificate for git.xxx.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/salt/utils/gitfs.py", line 1864, in _fetch
    fetch_results = origin.fetch(**fetch_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygit2/remote.py", line 147, in fetch
    payload.check_error(err)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygit2/callbacks.py", line 93, in check_error
    check_error(error_code)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygit2/errors.py", line 65, in check_error
    raise GitError(message)
_pygit2.GitError: user rejected certificate for git.xxx.local
```

To configure GitLab as a fileserver, I created this new file /etc/salt/master.d/file.conf on the Salt master:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/reactor
    - /srv/salt

fileserver_backend:
  - sseapi
  - gitfs
  - roots

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://git.xxx.local/root/ssc.git

gitfs_user:
  - root

gitfs_password:
  - root_password
```

Question: is this a GitLab issue where the root user needs some special configuration, or is this a Salt issue?

I have installed GitLab 14.0.1 and configured it with a CA-signed certificate of my org (not self-signed). Both Salt and GitLab have CA-signed certs and everything looks OK there. This does not look like a "invalid cert" type of message where the root cert cannot be found, but a "user rejected certificate" issue (whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that your gitfs user (root) hasn't [accepted the remote key](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html)

The current docs explain:

> To use SSH authentication, it is necessary to have the remote repository's SSH host key in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. If the master is also a minion, this can be done using the ssh.set_known_host function:

But

> If not, then the easiest way to add the key is to su to the user (usually root) under which the salt-master runs and attempt to login to the server via SSH:

```
$ sudo -s
Password:
# ssh gitlab.com
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (192.x.x.x)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.x.x.x' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```